# TCPDF imageSVG() rendering issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, svg, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library to render SVG File as -

```
$pdf->ImageSVG($img_file, 0, 0, $this->tcpdf->getPageWidth(), $this->tcpdf->getPageHeight(), '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
```

I am using these SVG images but these are not rendered correctly:

https://pairroxz.com/card_img/diamonds_ace.svg

https://pairroxz.com/card_img/hearts_ace.svg

but this rendered little bit good:

https://pairroxz.com/card_img/clubs_ace.svg

https://pairroxz.com/card_img/diamonds_3.svg

But I need diamonds_ace.svg and hearts_ace.svg correctly. I am unable to do that, for these 2 images result was:

[image]
[image]

for the other 2 results is - 
[image]
[image]

Comment: From what you are saying you have problems with the svg elements with gradients like clubs_ace.svg However images without gradients like diamonds_3.svg are rendered correctly. You may try removing the gradients to see if this works better for you

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, you are right, images with gradient is a problem but isn't there a way to solve this, as a user might upload gradient-based SVG.

Comment: I need to switch to SVG images because while working with png to generate PDF using this library taking lots of time.

Comment: @ChiragJain - This is a common complaint with TCPDF. It doesn't implement the entire SVG standard and there are plenty of edge cases it doesn't handle correctly so many SVG files will not render correctly. With TCPDF to allow these files to render correctly, you'd basically need to have ImageMagick rasterize them by calling `setRasterizeVectorImages` method with `true` as the argument. Unfortunately, that may make it run too slowly.